# Trying to access TextView children in a ListView returns null values

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

I am trying to make an mp3 player for Android. I've loaded all the tracks in the player in to a ListView (track is a TextView):

```
String[] titles = player.getTitles();
trackList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.track,titles));
```

When I try to paint the currently playing track red, it paints random children or crashes due to a nullpointer exception. I've tried every which way and have gotten to the point where I don't quite understand how the ListView methods work.

These are the methods I use to paint every track black, and then the selected one red:

```
public void paintBlack() {
    for (int i = trackList.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i < trackList.getLastVisiblePosition(); i++){
        if (trackList.getChildAt(i)==null) {
            System.out.println("Child is somehow null");
            return;
        }

        ((TextView)trackList.getChildAt(i)).setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
    }
}

public void paintRed() {
    for (int i = trackList.getFirstVisiblePosition(); i < trackList.getLastVisiblePosition();i++){
    if (trackList.getChildAt(i)==null) {
        System.out.println("Child is somehow null");
        return;
    }

    String view = ((TextView)trackList.getChildAt(i)).getText().toString();
    if (player.getTrack().equals(view)){
        ((TextView)trackList.getChildAt(i)).setTextColor(Color.RED);
    }           
}
```

I call the setSelection method before repainting so the view is always at the correct track:

```
public void updateTrackList() {
    trackList.setSelection(player.getCurrent());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Acessing a ListView's child views directly is considered bad practice and may lead to misbehavior.

Use a custom array adapter instead.

In the getView() method just set the color depending on whether the item at the index is playing.

Comment: Not sure, how to use custom adapters, but I will look in to it.